# Detecting anomalies in user access permissions

Tags: ruby, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to do some data mining on a company's access permissions. I'm trying to cluster different groups together according to the access they have, and then determine if someone's access is suspect because none of their group peers have that access. I'm just looking for an algorithm that might help me with this. It's pretty much an inverse recommendation system (i.e. Netflix, Amazon). Here's a simple example:

```
    Person 1 has access to files A, B, E
    Person 2 has access to files A, B
    Person 3 has access to files A, B
    Person 4 has access to files C, D, E
    Person 5 has access to files C, D
    Person 6 has access to files C, D, E
```

I want to be able to recognize without classifying it (unsupervised learning) that Persons 1-3 and Persons 4-6 are function similarly and are likely in the same group, because of their similar file access (clustering). After we identify the clusters, then we flag anomalous access, which is Person 1 with file E.

I tried to look into the AI4R ruby library, but came to a dead end. There are so many algorithms to choose from. I just need to be pointed the right way. Thanks.

Comment: what about a simple group_by? Might give you an overview.

Answer (score 0):

A straight forward way of doing this is to build feature vectors for each person and use the [cosine similarity](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/dot-products-1.html) / dot product as measure of similarity between the two. The feature vector would be something like (A=1, B=0, C=1...) and so on. When you compute  If your data is too sparse, i.e. too many access options, you may end up with very low similarity measures.

You could also build a reference (feature) matrix of how two features/access relate to each other, that is how similar they are to each other (say a value between 0 and 1). The similarity measure between two vectors can be a little smarter, as you take the weighted average:  Sum(f1, f2)/(nr(f1)*nr(f2))  where f1 is a feature/access form person 1, and f2 is a feature/access from person 2. nr(f1) = total features of person 1, and nr(f2) total features of person 2.

Say now you have measures of how each person relates to another person. Now you can use an [agglomerative clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering) strategy, which will allow you to end up with a predefined (meaning you set this limit) number of clusters. Or you can set rules about the maximal delta between the centroids of clusters to allow for agglomeration, which could make the process stop at some unpredicted stage (i.e. you end up with an unspecified number of clusters).

These are very simple strategies. The feature matrix requires domain knowledge, and takes time to build especially if you have a lot of features/access types.